# Ngrx issue with AOT in angular

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx

I have made my app using redux (ngrx) and it all works fine in dev mode, but in a production build, I am using AOT and it gives me this error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object`, here it says the source is combineReducers. How this can be resolved. Here is my code:

```
// reducer.ts

import { DynamicComponent, FieldTypeReducer, FormCreate, FormGroup, FormList, FormTemplates, FormPreview, FormView } from './forms';

const reducers = {
    dynamicComponent: DynamicComponent,
    fieldType: FieldTypeReducer,
    formCreate: FormCreate,
    formGroup: FormGroup,
    formList: FormList,
    formTemplates: FormTemplates,
    formPreview: FormPreview,
    formView: FormView
};

export default reducers;


// app.module.ts
import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { StoreDevtoolsModule } from '@ngrx/store-devtools';
import { StoreModule, ActionReducer, MetaReducer } from '@ngrx/store';

// Reducer
import reducers from './reducer';


@NgModule({
  imports: [

    StoreModule.forRoot(reducers),
    StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument({
      maxAge: 25
    })
  ],
  providers: [],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

a fix exists for this AOT compilation error with nrgx here : 
[fix(Store): Use existing reducers when not using an InjectionToken](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/pull/254)

Comment: is it possible for you to send the implementation, I am not able to resolve it using given link